# Simple XSLT transformation into ABAP Object

Tags: object, xslt, abap

I'm again stuck with a transformation from XML into ABAP. This time, I want to put the XML data directly into an ABAP Object. 
My XML looks like this:

```
<qualityStatus>
    <address>0</address>
    <bounceRisk>0</bounceRisk>
    <checked>1</checked>
    <domain>1</domain>
    <domainScores>
        <domainScore>
            <domain>gmx.de</domain>
            <score>0.8333333134651184</score>
        </domainScore>
        <domainScore>
            <domain>ggs.de</domain>
            <score>0.6666666269302368</score>
        </domainScore>
        <domainScore>
            <domain>xyz.de</domain>
            <score>0.6666666269302368</score>
        </domainScore>
    </domainScores>
    <extSyntax>1</extSyntax>
    <mailserver>1</mailserver>
    <mailserverDiagnosis>1</mailserverDiagnosis>
    <probability>1</probability>
    <syntax>1</syntax>
</qualityStatus>
```

*Edit: I changed back to a XSLT transformation, shortened to one attribute it looks like this:*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/qualityStatus">
    <asx:abap version="1.0" xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml">
        <asx:values>
            <ROOT href="#o26"/>
        </asx:values>
        <asx:heap xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:abap="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/built-in"
                  xmlns:cls="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/classes/global"
                  xmlns:dic="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/dictionary">
            <cls:ZCL_ADDRESS_QUALITY id="o26" >
                <local.ZCL_ADDRESS_QUALITY>
                    <W_ADDRESS>
                        <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
                    </W_ADDRESS>
                    <!--More attributes here-->
                </local.ZCL_ADDRESS_QUALITY>
            </cls:ZCL_ADDRESS_QUALITY>
        </asx:heap>
    </asx:abap>
</xsl:template>
```

My object attributes are all public right now, because I thought this could be the problem. However, setter and getter do exist. Yes, my class does implement the interface if_serializable_object.

```
 DATA:
  w_address             TYPE char1,
  w_bouncerisk          TYPE char1,
  w_checked             TYPE char1,
  w_decoded             TYPE stringval,
  w_domain              TYPE char1,
  w_domainscores        TYPE z_domainscore_t, "Table type for name + score
  w_extsyntax           TYPE char1,
  w_mailserver          TYPE char1,
  w_mailserverdiagnosis TYPE char1,
  w_probability         TYPE char1,
  w_syntax              TYPE char1,
  w_syntaxwarnings      TYPE z_syntaxwarnings_t. "Table of syntaxwarnings
```

Finally, I call my transformation with an instance of my class:

```
CALL TRANSFORMATION zst_addressquality
      SOURCE XML lw_xml
      RESULT result = lo_addressquality.
```

Now, when debugging through the transformation code, it successfully notices all fields of the given lw_xml and appears to write them into the object lo_addressquality. But the object attributes stay empty afterwards. 
When testing the serialization, I can access result which contains my object, but result-w_address (and all others) are empty. 
While testing, I created a structure with completely identical names and types. With it, it worked as intended. 

What am I missing? Is there anything else I have to watch out for when working with transformation into ABAP Objects?
_Edit: After changing to the XSLT, I can get until W_ADDRESS before my code throws an CX_XSLT_ABAP_CALL_ERROR. So, I'm still not able to access the object'S attributes properly. :|_

Comment: Please post a very simple case so that we can reproduce: **a class with one public instance attribute**, the transformation for **only this field** (no need of over complexifying it as it's not the subject of the question), one XML example **with only this field**, and the code for deserializing (you did it).

Answer (score 4):

Objects can be serialized/deserialized only with an **XSL** transformation. It's not possible to do it with a simple transformation, dixit [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenabap_st.htm):

> ST programs are restricted to the transformation of elementary and structured ABAP data, along with internal tables. The transformation of reference variables and referenced objects is not currently supported.

The XSL transformation must convert the XML into [ASXML](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenabap_xslt_asxml.htm), which in short corresponds to a structure like this:

```
<?xml ...?>
<asx:abap xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml" version="1.0">
  <asx:values>
    ...
  </asx:values>
  <asx:heap>
    ...
  </asx:heap>
</asx:abap>
```

The easiest way to understand what the ASXML should look like is to serialize your object reference using the [identity transformation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abenabap_xslt_id.htm) (it's an XSL transformation), and then adapt your transformation to produce the same kind of asXML:

```
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE anyRootName = yourObjectReference RESULT XML asXMLutf8xstring.
```

Example:

```
REPORT.
CLASS serialization_demo DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_serializable_object.
    DATA attribute TYPE i.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA obj_ref TYPE REF TO serialization_demo.
  DATA xstring TYPE xstring.
  CREATE OBJECT obj_ref.
  obj_ref->attribute = 5.
  CALL TRANSFORMATION id " serialize
        SOURCE root = obj_ref
        RESULT XML xstring.
  CLEAR obj_ref.
  CALL TRANSFORMATION id " deserialize
        SOURCE XML xstring
        RESULT root = obj_ref.
```

ASXML (in the xstring variable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asx:abap version="1.0" xmlns:asx="http://www.sap.com/abapxml">
  <asx:values>
    <ROOT href="#o3"/>
  </asx:values>
  <asx:heap xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abap="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/built-in" xmlns:cls="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/classes/global" xmlns:dic="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/types/dictionary">
    <prg:SERIALIZATION_DEMO id="o3" xmlns:prg="http://www.sap.com/abapxml/classes/program/ZZSRO_TEST16I">
      <local.SERIALIZATION_DEMO>
        <ATTRIBUTE>5</ATTRIBUTE>
      </local.SERIALIZATION_DEMO>
    </prg:SERIALIZATION_DEMO>
  </asx:heap>
</asx:abap>
```

Comment: Thanks Sandra, I changed back to my XSLT. In the debugger, it breaks at the prg: tag. What does the prefix "local" mean? The serialization demo is the class name, but what does local refer to? The package of where the class resides?

Comment: It's explained in the [ASXML](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenasxml_class_instances.htm) documentation: "If the class is a local class, prefix `local` is added in front of the name, separated by a point (.), to distinguish it from a global class of the same name."

Comment: As you have edited your question, I can see that you didn't follow my advice: the easiest way to understand what the ASXML should look like is **to serialize** (convert a variable into XML) your object reference using the ID transformation, see how the asXML looks like (you'd see that it doesn't contain the prefix `local`, because you don't have a local class, you only have a class pool ZCL_ADDRESS_QUALITY), and then adapt your transformation to produce the same asXML.